# Is there a piece of equipment that protects against vibration?

Tags: tools, safety, powertools, protection

I'm doing a lot of work with a Sawzall reciprocating saw and the vibrations are very uncomfortable. After about 30 seconds, I have to stop because my arms are itchy from vibrating too much.

In addition to being uncomfortable, I'm also concerned that it may do long term damage.

Is there any type of PPE (personal protection equipment) that protects against vibrations or makes it more comfortable to work with tools that vibrate a lot?

Comment: We're not doctors, one option is a different kind of saw.  You're not required to use a reciprocating saw specifically. Also are you sure you are using the tool correctly, bracing correctly and using a quality tool?

Comment: I have often found that reciprocating saws vibrate much more when I do not press the front blade guard firmly against the work surface.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are using the tool wrong. With a sawsall I have seen many people try and hold the saw in place, I am a big guy 6'5" and close to 300lbs and I could do this for a few minutes but prefer to use the guard to stop the tool from pulling my arms around. Push the guard up to the work and don't try to feed two fast or it will push back. When properly cutting it takes very little effort to hold the tool in place and let it do the cutting. If you do not use the guard to keep the tool from moving the sawsall is putting your arms through what it would take to cut using a hack saw. Keep the saw tight to the work and let it do the work.

Answer (score 3):

You can try buying gloves that have gel padding on your palm to help, but excessive vibration is a sign that you're using the reciprocating saw incorrectly. To reduce vibration, push the saw's pivot shoe against the piece you're cutting.